# Using the REST API in D2L logs the user out

Tags: desire2learn

When I make use of the REST API in D2L, the user's login to D2L is lost.  If he then wants to go back to D2L to do something else, he must log in again.

For example, I am using the REST API to capture grades from D2L and insert them into our SIS.  It works nicely, but then when the user wants to go back into D2L to capture grades for a different class, he has to login to D2L again.

Is that something that can changed so that the user is able to go back into D2L without logging in again.

Or is there something I should be doing when I call the REST APIs that would cause D2L not to log the user out?

Chris Collins
Academic Development
Bob Jones University

Answer (score 0):

The current versions of the libraries for rest connections include a parameter that that changes the login sequence in the browser and has the side effect of logging out the browser session.

So this behaviour is from the client library and not the use of REST itself.

The fix that turns off this parameter in the library is expected to be checked in later this week.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that.  I will look forward to the fix.